# How to get the SPD Workflow Instance column name from the document library using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, powershell, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I am having a SPD 2010 workflow created and deployed in my site collection and  published globally as a reusable workflow. I have configured the workflow in my document library by associating it with my custom content types.

How will I ensure that the workflow has been triggered successfully using PowerShell?

I have 158 sub sites in my site collection and having 10 document libraries so I can not verify whether the workflow instance been triggered successfully or not in all the document libraries and all sub sites. So I have to write a PowerShell to get the column name of workflow  instance.

How to get the workflow instance column name from the  document library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://weburl
$list = $web.Lists["Document Library"]

//Get Workflow Association Name
foreach($association in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
{
    write-host $association.name

    //Find and init $associationName here
}

foreach ($field in $list.Fields)
{
    if($field.Type -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::WorkflowStatus -and $field.Title -eq $associationName)
    {
        //$field is what you are looking for
    }
}
```